# Conditioned filtering in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, filtering, tidyverse

I am trying to write a function that automates the filtering process for me. Consider this example here focusing on the data dataframe:

```
#generate mock dataframe
set.seed(1)

number <-c("4","5","6")

##groups
colors <- c("red","orange","green")
fruit <- c("apple","tomato","banana")
animal <- c("chicken","pork","cow")


vector_colors <-map(colors, ~ str_c(.,number, sep = "_"))  %>%  reduce(c)
vector_fruit <-map(fruit, ~ str_c(.,number, sep = "_"))  %>%  reduce(c)
vector_animal <-map(animal, ~ str_c(.,number, sep = "_"))  %>%  reduce(c)


vector <- c(vector_colors,vector_fruit,vector_animal)
```

```
#dataframe I'll be working with
data <-  tibble(name = vector,
                rank = runif(27, 1, 99))
```

I want a function or a tidyverse/base R workflow that prints me one item per group (i.e colors, fruit and animal) such that the printed item has the lowest rank compared to all other items within its group. In that seeded example, the wanted result will be the following vector:

```
wanted_result <-c("orange_5","apple_6","cow_6")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a look-up table of types, extract the prefixes, join to the types, and group by types to pull the names with minimum ranks:

```
library(dplyr)
type_lookup = tibble(
  prefix = c(colors, fruit, animal),
  type = rep(c("color", "fruit", "animal"), times = c(length(colors), length(fruit), length(animal)))
)

data %>%
  mutate(prefix = str_extract(name, pattern = ".*(?=_)")) %>%
  left_join(type_lookup, by = "prefix") %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  slice_min(rank) %>%
  pull(name)
# [1] "cow_6"    "orange_5" "apple_4"
```